# Hibernate - byNaturalId not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a user entity identified by two natural ids, something like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints =
{ @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "nick") })
public User()
{}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private id;

@Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 31)
@NaturalId(mutable = true)
private String email;   

@Column(name = "nick", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 31)
@NaturalId(mutable = false)
private String nick;
```

However, when I try to execute

```
session.byNaturalId(User.class).with(LockOptions.READ).using("email", "admin@mail.com").load();
```

it throws an exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Entity [pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.shared.model.entities.User] defines its natural-id with 2 properties but only 1 were specified
at org.hibernate.event.spi.ResolveNaturalIdEvent.<init>(ResolveNaturalIdEvent.java:75)
at org.hibernate.event.spi.ResolveNaturalIdEvent.<init>(ResolveNaturalIdEvent.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$BaseNaturalIdLoadAccessImpl.resolveNaturalId(SessionImpl.java:2607)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$NaturalIdLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2722)
at pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.server.model.orm.StorageManager.getByNaturalId(StorageManager.java:217)
at pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.test.local.MyHibernateTest.test1(MyHibernateTest.java:37)
at pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.test.local.MyHibernateTest.main(MyHibernateTest.java:23)
```

Why is this? I think it's also due to the log of the SQL syntax generated by Hibernate. Indeed, it is strange (redundant) at this point and I think it's the cause of the exception

```
Hibernate: 
    alter table user 
        add constraint UK_t8tbwelrnviudxdaggwr1kd9b  unique (email, nick)
Hibernate: 
    alter table user 
        add constraint UK_ob8kqyqqgmefl0aco34akdtpe  unique (email)
Hibernate: 
    alter table user 
        add constraint UK_pvnbxcfihb58o5n2n1fnc7fh1  unique (nick)
```

EDIT: Reading the code again, I thought that the problem could be related to the `@UniqueConstraints` annotations. However, even if I try to remove one of them, Hibernate continues to genetate the above SQL syntax.

Comment: Can you show us some more detail about the values you are passing to the `using()` method in your code: `session.byNaturalId(User.class).with(LockOptions.READ).using(attributeName, value).load();`? It would help to see what `attributeName` and `value` are.

Comment: Basically, you're telling hibernate that your NaturalId is a combination of email and nick. So you would have to pass values for both attributes in the query.

Comment: @RicardoPerezHernando sure, I missed that :)

Comment: @John Why? It's not my object. I want to separate natural identifier.

Comment: @tigerjack89 Because by specifying the NaturalId annotation to both fields you're basically creating a composite natural key. See [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/10/22/immutable-and-naturalid-hibernate-specific-annotations/) (scroll down to "Composite Natural Id Example") for an example.

Comment: @John Get the point now. So, is there a way to have two different natural ids?

Comment: @tigerjack89 I fear not, though I don't have a source to support that claim. But you can still query by using your "ordinary" unique columns.

Comment: @John but it implies writing a HQL, isn't it? Or is it possible to retrieve an entity based on a unique constraint?

Comment: Have a look at the [Criteria API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html).

Comment: @John great! So, something like `session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .add(Restrictions.like("email", "admin@mail.com")).list()` ? It could be a right workaround (and definitely the accepted answer). Do you know why isn't possible? Specific design choice? Am I missing something on the subject?

Comment: @John a bit late, but you can definitely compose your comments in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the email address alone the NaturalId and then your query would work.

When two columns are identified as the NaturalId it creates a Composite Key.

Nick could still be used as a foreign Key.

Answer (score 0):

You've a composite naturalId key (email,nick) so you can have multiples results with simple email arg.
you've to use

```
session
   .byNaturalId(User.class)
   .with(LockOptions.READ)
   .using("email", "admin@mail.com")
   .using("nick", "admin")
   .load();
```

You can also use Metamodel

```
session
   .byNaturalId(User.class)
   .with(LockOptions.READ)
   .using(User_.email.getName(), "admin@mail.com")
   .using(User_.nick.getName(), "admin")
   .load();
```